# How to calculate Legendre Polynomials using Orthogonal projections

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

In Linear Algebra, how do I calculate the first four Legendre Polynomials using 
basic rules of orthogonal projections given the following inner product space:
$$
\int f\,g 
$$
where $f$ and $g$ are vectors in the polynomial space (let's say it's finite).

I've been able to develop the the Legendre Polynomial of 1 which is $1/\sqrt{2}$.
However, I cannot seem to get to the values of $x$, I get stuck with a constant value:
$$
\text{Legendre}(x) = x - \frac{1}{2}
$$
What is the right way to perform this?

Thank you

Comment: This is exactly the Gram-Schmidt procedure in $\mathbb{R}^4$, only with a different scalar product. The identification is $e_1=1, e_2=x, e_3=x^2, e_4=x^3$ and the scalar product is the one you gave, which makes *not* $e_1, e_2, e_3, e_4$ into an orthonormal base, as you can see: for example, $\langle e_1, e_1\rangle= \int_{-1}^1 x\cdot x\, dx=2/3$.

Comment: Did you use Gram Schmidt process?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to build Legendre polynomials manually (we wil use the interval $[-1,1]$ and normalise them to get $L_p(1)=1$), you can use the following procedure (note that $p$-th Legendre polynomial has degree $p$).

1) zero degree, $L_0(1)=L_0$, hence $L_0(x)=1$.

2) first degree, $L_0\bot L_1$, $ L_1 (1) =1 $. We take $L_1(x) = ax+b$, so we can write

$$0=\int_{-1}^1L_1(x)L_0dx= \int_{-1}^1 (ax+b)dx= 2b,$$hence $b=0$.

Next,
$$1= L_1 (x) =a  x $$
so we can take $a=1$.

3) second degree: $L_2(x) = ax^2+bx+c$, you impose orthogonality to $L_0$ and $L_1$ and normalise it to $L_2(1)=1$. This will give you three linear equations on $a$, $b$, $c$, which we are able to solve.

This iterative procedure gives all $L_p$. [This wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials) gives many properties of Legendre polynomials, take a look at it.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal It's nothing but Gram-Schmidt's orthogonalisation process with a little bit of tinkering.